# I have a residence permit for Norway. Can I travel to Switzerland without a passport?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, switzerland, norway

I am an Indian citizen currently in Norway and I have a residence permit. I have to travel to Switzerland but I do not have my passport with me as it is gone to another embassy for visa stamping.

Can I travel to Switzerland without my passport? I am not sure what they will ask me at Zurich airport and also when I return to Oslo.